# Haskell IO function type mismatch

Tags: haskell, io, functional-programming, tuples, monads

what is the problem with the following code:

```
nextMatch :: (a -> Bool) -> [IO a] -> (IO a, [IO a])
nextMatch f (x:xs) = do
    s <- x
    if f s then (return x, xs)
        else nextMatch f xs
```

The compile error says:

```
src\Main.hs:364:10:
    Couldn't match expected type `(IO a, t0)' with actual type `IO a'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: s <- x
    In the expression:
      do { s <- x;
           if f s then (return x, xs) else nextMatch f xs }
    In an equation for `nextMatch':
        nextMatch f (x : xs)
          = do { s <- x;
                 if f s then (return x, xs) else nextMatch f xs }
```

I want a function which searches a list for a match and returns the matched element plus the remaining list, as tuple.

I am still quite new to haskell, so this problem might be something quite simple...

Thanks!
Chris

Comment: A general comment--Monadic arguments (such as `IO [a]`, or your `[IO a]`), are almost always a bad idea. Impure code usually takes pure arguments, using do-notation or `>>=` to apply them to monadic values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `x` if of type `IO a` , no need to re-return it, contrary to the tuple which definitely need to be injected into the monad.

```
if f s then return $ (x, xs)
```

But, that not the only issue, as your are into the `IO` monad and your signature doesn't reflect it, as you return type is `(IO a, [IO a])` it should be `IO (IO a, [IO a])`. 
Then your code should be as follow.

```
nextMatch :: (a -> Bool) -> [IO a] -> IO (IO a, [IO a])
nextMatch f (x:xs) =  
  do 
    done <- fmap f x  
    if done
    then return $ (x, xs)
    else nextMatch f xs
```

Anyway I don't know what you are trying to do but the signature of your function look pretty awkward. It should look much more like `nextMatch :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> (a, [a])`, then using `return` is enough to build a monadic version of it. `nextMatchIO = return $ nextMatch` and then plug this computation into your control flow using other function, provided by `Control.Monad`.

Comment: You're right, but to avoid extra computation which are painful for my brain I took the party that most of the time I'll use `return $ expr` in place of `return expr`. Of course, this rule does not apply when I've to write professional code, then I take the time to ask me the question if I have to use `$` or not. Anyway thank for your remarks.

Comment: @zurgl I recently came to the conclusion that I need to use `$` much *less* in monadic code. It makes it painful to move stuff around to using `>>=` or applicative style, because I keep tripping myself up by thinking that I can convert `a <- g $ b; f a` to `g $ b >>= f`, or to `f <$> g $ b`.

Answer (score 9):

You shouldn't need to deal with `IO` here. This is how I'd implement it as a pure function (I added the `Maybe` type since there might not be a next match):

```
nextMatch :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Maybe (a, [a])
nextMatch _ []     = Nothing
nextMatch f (x:xs) = if f x then Just (x, xs) else nextMatch f xs
```

As a beginner, if you're taking something with `IO` as an input to a function, or if you're returning a data structure with `IO` inside of it, chances are you're probably doing something wrong (probably in the code you want to call this from).

Answer (score -1):

Your function should be returning a tuple. If my Haskell is still up to par, I would try putting parens around your return function "if f s then (return (x, xs))".

Comment: Your Haskell is not still "up to par" :)